# Flutter Version app differently based on platform

Tags: flutter, versioning

I am in the process of building an app that will run across 3 different platforms, Mobile, desktop and web. Is there a way I can version them differently in pubspecy.yaml.

Current pubspec.yaml

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
```

What I want to try

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

mobile_version: 1.0.1
desktop_version: 1.1.0
web_version: 1.1.1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.1 <3.0.0"
```

Is the above possible?

Comment: Just add branches to your repo for the different platforms and change the `version` number in each branch.